# Can i host google chrome extension on my own server?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, publish

I have created a small google chrome extension (just a simple html popup)
that itself is a part of desktop app. Now i want to give users ability to install
this extension, but i don't want to publish it to chrome store, as it is not standalone app but only small plugin, that will not work without desktop app installed.
I read here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting 
that i can create .crx file and host in on my own server.
But in same time this page said: "Warning: As of Chrome 33, Windows users can only download extensions hosted in the Chrome Web store, except for installs via enterprise policy or developer mode "

So i am confusing, am i able to create .crx file, host it on my server, and allow windows users install it on their browsers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes with the limitations stated in *"Warning: As of Chrome 33, Windows users can only download extensions hosted in the Chrome Web store, except for installs via enterprise policy or developer mode "*

Which means that the user cannot download it from any private sever and install it. It has to be installed trough the company GPO and the system need to be joined to an Active Directory domain (A/D).You can download an ADM or ADMX from

https://enterprise.google.com/chrome/chrome-browser